# Why is there no method of contacting a moderator regarding actions taken on your behalf?

Tags: feature-request, moderators

Since there is no where for me to send a message to a moderator, who has in my opinion, badly abused his power, I'm asking this question.

In this question [Why do some English speakers pronounce “fête” as “fate”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32633/why-do-we-english-speakers-pronounce-fete-as-fate) my answer was deleted.

I've read the FAQ, and they offer no legit reason why. The subjective decision that it had no value was clearly made by a mod named Kosmonaut. His rep is *very high* for a member of only 10 months, so I assume he is trusted and respected, and I want to know what prompted this decision. In addition, I want to know why there is no notification or appeal, much less a way to discuss that decision politely with the people involved.

Comment: I guess your idea of "discuss politely" differs from mine — the kind I know doesn't start with "you have badly abused your power".

Comment: I guess it does. Mine starts with actual trying to communicate, rather than taking arbitrary action without any communication at all.

Comment: There *is* a way to discuss the decision with the people involved, and you have  discovered it all by yourself and are using it right now. People flagged your stuff, a moderator acted on the flags, now you object to the mod's decision on meta. Excellent. This is exactly how it works, has always worked, and is supposed to work — on all 50+ sites of the network.

Comment: @zenbike I know I come late and this matter has already been discussed, but it's not true that your answer was deleted: As @Kosmonaut said, it was converted into a comment, so please, could you edit that part in your question?

Comment: @Kosmonaut Oh, please. Targeting uses and abusing power is what's really despicable. Saying, "You have abused your power," isn't rude one bit. It's a factual response to abuse.

Answer (score 8):

I simply converted your answer to a comment, as it didn't answer the question ("why do English speakers do this?"), though it provided a useful data point ("we don't do this where I am from").  You can see your comment there under the question.  This particular case was originally brought to my attention by flags from other users.

There are ways to discuss things of this nature, by flagging the content in question or pinging me in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-and-usage).

---

(Also, this site has only existed for 10 months.)

Comment: The way I see it, you did abuse your power. And frankly, I was pissed, because you did it with no communication to me regarding the matter. I edited my answer to reflect the fact that it only referred to AmE, and I included the information that I've lived in 7 countries and 26 states, and still never heard it pronounced the way they say "English speakers" do.  If you felt the need to delete the post based on flags from 2 Aussie fellows who took umbrage to it, for some unknown reason, I don't feel that was right or fair.

Comment: As for the question re: your reputation, I didn't intend to say you hadn't earned it. I was frankly amazed that you could have, in such a short time.

Comment: The point of this question is still valid, and still open? Why is there no method of communication with those who edit or manage other peoples posts, without violating the purpose of the site by using a question to start that dialog? Flagging the content no longer works if it's been deleted, nor does it get the direct attention of the mod who made the change. I was unaware of the ability to find a specific person in chat, and if that's the case, that may work. Although you have to be online for that message to reach you, I assume?

Comment: Flagging is only needed while the content is visible.  I like having the flagging option, and I've used it a few times on SuperUser.com to draw attention to spam (mostly), and I'll do the same thing here if I believe the content warrants it (I'm not concerned with minor nonsense, but I do believe that major offenses can do a lot of damage to a community).  So far I find that most of the questions, answers, and comments in this web site are interesting and helpful.

Comment: @zenbike: no, I would see it the next time I am online. I'm sorry that you feel upset. Stackexchange sites work a bit differently from other sites, so sometimes it takes some getting used to. Again, I did not delete your post; I converted it to a comment.

Comment: @zenbike, I don't understand why you're making all this fuss honestly.  When your contribution is *not* an answer (or worse if it is a sloppy answer) and you post it *as an answer*, the odds are pretty high that it will get down-voted by a significant proportion of the readers. By converting it to a comment, @Kosmonaut **shielded you** from that... hm...*fate* because comments cannot be down-voted.  Otherwise you would have had to delete it **yourself** to recoup your  rep...

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I'd have expected that at least. But what about if the "mention" is in a comment to an answer neither written nor commented on by the "addressee", though he has posted elsewhere on the same question/page?

Answer (score 1):

Upvotes for *Kosmonaut*'s Answer may simply reflect the fact that he commands the respect of many of us - which is why he has a high rep in the first place.

I understand *zenbike*'s frustration. It's largely irrelevant whether *Kosmonaut*'s action was ideal/defensible/questionable, just as *zenbike*'s potentially confrontational phrasing at points doesn't really bear on the merits of his case.

The key point is that *here we are talking about it*. And as RegDwight says, that's the way EL&U is *supposed to work*. Personally I don't even care much about the original Question involved, much less the merits of *zenbike*'s Answer which was converted to Comment.

My understanding is that *if* a poster has a problem with any moderator action they can always post a comment to *@AnyModeratorName* requesting discussion. Or indeed post in **meta**, as actually happened. It would probably end up with the right person getting involved soon enough. OP in this case obviously knew which moderator was involved, so that wasn't even an issue.

TL;DR: The system *does* work. If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: I didn't know about the "TL;DR:" abbreviation before... :D

Comment: @Alenanno: Only came across it myself last month. Then got pulled up for failing to include the semicolon, which apparently is *nearly always* included!

Comment: @Alenanno [What does "TL;DR:" mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10659/what-does-tldr-mean)

Comment: @kiamlaluno Sì avevo già visto, ma grazie! :)

Comment: If you are talking of comments on the main site, then _@AnyModeratorName_ doesn't work, if _AnyModeratorName_ didn't write a comment for the same post, before.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Are you sure? And by *the same post*, do you mean the specific Question or Answer within which one might comment *@AnyModeratorName*, or anything within the EL&U page for that Question? I assumed you could at least "mailbox" any *@UserName* present on the page, even if it might not work for known/active users who happen not to have posted at all there.

Comment: I am sure; if _AnyModeratorName_ is not who commented in the answer, _@AnyModeratorName_ does not work; if _AnyModeratorName_ is the author of the answer, then the author of the answer gets notifications for each comments left to the answer. The same is true for who is the author of the question, who gets notified of each comment, including the comments left for the answers, as far as I remember. In other words, _@username_ does not work as in chat.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It actually works if the user edited the post, and in the case of closed questions, if the moderator closed the question.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main features of this site is that anybody with 2000 rep (not just anointed moderators) can edit other people's posts.  It's never been a secret, and personally I think it's extremely useful.  Of course it is theoretically open to abuse, but so is any system.  It is certainly better than letting the site be taken over by people who say "This is the answer, and I don't need anybody else's opinion.  I know all about English."

Also, it can only be judged by the site users, who seem happy at present: anyone who strongly objects to the system probably won't become a site user anyhow.

Comment: Attitude like that is one reason why they won't. Nowhere in my answer on that question did I claim anything of the sort, and I was not offended because it was edited. It wasn't edited. It was deleted, without cause. Yes, any system is open to abuse, which is why you need a balancing system to address perceived abuses. If I had a way to discuss it with the person who did it, or they had the courtesy to talk to me about why, or even (gasp) explain the problem and let me fix it myself, so that I might learn, I wouldn't have needed to ask this question here.

Comment: In addition, this answer is exactly the sort of answer I was just excoriated for posting. Opinion, without basis or relevance to the question asked. I didn't ask your opinion about editing. I asked if you thought we could use an appeal/communication system of some kind.

Comment: As for the site users being happy with it, this one isn't. As should be obvious from the conversation about this topic at all. And what I'm asking is for the site users to judge whether more is needed. That is after all what a meta question is for.

Comment: @zenbike: this is meta.SE. It is a place for discussion, so the answers don't have the same kind of strict formatting we have on main sites. Voting also works differently on meta sites. Take a bit of time to familiarize yourself with the Stackexchange network and you'll see most aspects have a logic to them. It may not be the way you would run the site, but the thing that makes SE so much better than Yahoo Answers is the strict structure.

Comment: @zenbike: I don't see any point arguing further, since we are starting from such different positions.  But could you edit your question to cut it down to a reasonable size?  At present, it starts with 'Why was my post deleted?' (it wasn't), and goes on to 'Is there an appeal system or place to object? Should there be?' and possibly 'How does the system work?' and 'Should it be changed?' which is a lot to fit into one question.